# Accessing BufferedImages to update JFrame components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, bufferedimage, xuggle

Basically, I am extracting images from a video in realtime as BufferedImages and displaying them within a JFrame after processing. Unfortunately I am very bad with swing, so while the images show up within the JFrame as intended, it spawns a new JFrame for every new image (24 per second).

I send the BufferedImages to the GUI with:

```
UserInterface.main(currentFrame);
```

Where they are received by my GUI class, which is essentially A JLabel containing the current image inside a JPanel inside a JFrame:

```
public class UserInterface extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main(BufferedImage inputImage) throws IOException 
{   
    UserInterface frame = new UserInterface(inputImage);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public UserInterface(BufferedImage inputImage) throws IOException 
{       
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    setBounds(50, 50, 1024, 768);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(inputImage));
    add(imageLabel);
    imageLabel.setBounds(11, 60, 480, 360);
    contentPane.add(imageLabel);        
}
```

Can anyone advise on how to break this up to make just 1 JFrame appear, in which I can display all the images dynamically?

Comment: `contentPane.setLayout(null);`  Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor `imageLabel` to be a class member of `UserInterface`, and update its backing `ImageIcon` every frame. However, this might too slow, in which case you'll want to create your own panel class that overrides `paintComponent(Graphics)` to draw the frame image. Finally, you should manually trigger repaints for that panel by calling `paintImmediately(getBounds())`. Something along the following lines should work:

```
public class VideoPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage frame;

    public VideoPanel() {

    }

    public void setFrame(BufferedImage image) {
        this.frame = image;
        paintImmediately(getBounds());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(frame == null) return;
        int width = frame.getWidth();
        int height = frame.getHeight();
        Dimension boundary = getSize();
        // Scale image dimensions with aspect ratio to fit inside the panel
        int bwidth;
        int bheight = ((bwidth = boundary.width) * height) / width;
        if (bheight > boundary.height) {
            bwidth = ((bheight = boundary.height) * width) / height;
        }
        // Center it in the space given
        int x = Math.abs(boundary.width - bwidth) / 2;
        int y = Math.abs(boundary.height - bheight) / 2;
        g.drawImage(frame, x, y, bwidth, bheight, null);
    }
}
```

You'll also likely want to clear the background of the panel before you draw on it, to prevent rendering artifacts.

Comment: Your paintComponent method breaks the painting chain.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've updated my answer to include a super call to paintComponent. My (perhaps unfounded) logic for not including it was that a video panel will likely never have children, and clearing the canvas yourself (with fillRect) is quite a bit faster than delegating to super.paintComponent.

Comment: @Nox `paintComponent` paints the background, but failing to clear the `Graphics` context could lead to other paint artifacts showing up, which you don't really want. *"and clearing the canvas yourself (with fillRect) is quite a bit faster than delegating to super.paintComponent"* - Do you have metrics for that, because essentially that's all `super.paintComponent` does, by default

Comment: @MadProgrammer Fair enough. I should've been more clear on what I meant by "clearing the canvas yourself". `super.paintComponent` eventually calls `fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight())`, which does more work than is necessary: since we know the frame will always be written, we only need to repaint on the sides of image, and not the image itself. Last time I was in the same position as the OP, performing selective background painting sped up the video playback significantly when the window was maximized on a large-ish screen.

Comment: *"However, this will likely be too slow,.."* On what evidence do you base that statement?

Comment: @AndrewThompson `ImageIcon.setImage` has some overhead caused by its backing `MediaTracker`, which performs some `MediaEntry` instantiations and collection modifications. In the same vein, using an `ImageIcon` prevents the optimization of only clearing the image borders. Not that this should matter much, but since the OP is already performing a highly intensive decoding task, reducing the constant overhead even a bit should help.